# Constitution vs. Damage for Long Death Monk

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, optimization, monk

I'm working on making a monk character for a new 5e campaign. I'm pretty much done with the build, just have a question about a tweak I want to make. Right now I feel like the monk lacks in damage and I want to increase my damage, but I don't want to lose out a bunch on survivability.

Race: Hill Dwarf Monk (+2 Con, +1 Wis, Dwarven Toughness)
Class: Monk, Way of Long Death
Current Stats: Str: 10, Dex: 15, Con: 15, Int: 8, Wis: 16, Cha: 10.

Should I bring my constitution down from 15 to 12, and instead make my charisma 13, so I can multiclass into a warlock 1 level, for Hex and Eldritch Blast for range.  Hex will allow me to add 1d6 damage per hit and with flurry of blows I can potentially get 4d6 damage at higher levels.  Also eldritch blast provides a good ranged attack that scales at higher levels.
Is the damage gained through this method, worth the potential loss in health?

I am looking for better ways to improve damage for my monk. I know the monk class is meant to be played as attack and run, always on the move fighter, but I also want some higher damage.

This character is expected to got up to level 18-20 in the campaign.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. We specialise in handling questions that can have a single best or correct answer, and it sounds like you instead want to engage in a discussion about what your options are and what people would recommend for your character build. Since we're not a discussion forum we don't handle that kind of question very well, and I've closed this as primarily opinion-based. I suggest instead asking [one of these forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449) for guidance, such as the D&D Reddit.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE.  It would be helpful to extract the actual stats you have assigned to the build into this question, since links sometimes go bad.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get a feel for how this Q&A site is a bit different from other sites.  Glad you are here, happy gaming.

Comment: I should clarify you're not in trouble, and you're welcome to continue using the site. I do suggest following up with one of those forums, and we'll be happy to help you out here when you have a specific solveable problem with a potential best or correct answer available.

Comment: If you could take a look at this [meta question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1641/22566), it provides what makes for a good optimization question.  I suggest that your revise your question a bit to try and meet that style to help get it reopened.  As I understand your objectives, you want to optimize this monk for dealing damage. Right?  [Here is an optimization question that remains open](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115221/22566) to give an idea.

Comment: Got it. I'll take the stats out of the imgur link and move it into the question, and also reword the question.

Comment: @doppelgreener Changed my question. Made it more refined. What do you think?

Comment: @currymanswag What level are you starting at?  You're talking about multiclassing and a specific monk tradition so I assume you're planning this build for at least 3rd or 4th level?

Comment: @Teron Yup. But I'm sure our campaign will last until the higher levels. Level 18, possibly even level 20.